# Using natbib with agsm

Tags: punctuation, natbib, harvard-style

I am using `natbib` and `agsm` for harvard style referencing.  My related code is

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Then I am using `\citep{}` for citations. My problem is that in text I am getting
`(Author 2012)` but I want `(Author, 2012)` for multiple authors it is `(Author1 2012, Author2 2010)` and I want `(Author1, 2012; Author2, 2010)`.

Any Ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `natbib` many aspects can be easily configured: you need to set `citesep` (separation between two citations in the same place) and `aysep` (separation between author and year in a citation):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={;}, aysep={,}}

\begin{document}
\citep{Goossens:1994:LCb}

\citep{Knuth:1986:MB,Lamport:1994:LDP}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I used one of N. Beebe's databases.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will do what you want:

```
\usepackage[comma,colon]{natbib}
```

based on [this reference sheet](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf)